# Jquery get json value

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to get every first name from json text below:

```
[
{
"Contact":{
    "id":"4",
    "first_name":"Richat",
    "last_name":"Chhay",
    "phone":"930345435",
    }
},
{
"Contact":{
    "id":"31",
    "first_name":"Dara",
    "last_name":"Hong",
    "phone":"930345435",
    }
}
]
```

what I want is how to get first_name?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cZGL6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  **[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**  method to retrieve the value

```
$.each(data,function(i,val){
   alert(val.Contact.first_name);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fU5Gy/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
arr.forEach(function(elm){
  console.log(elm.Contact.first_name);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q5buH/)

Answer (score 0):

Get it as jsonArray and execute a loop on it, for each value in array get the name and output where you want it.

Comment: please add some code for better understanding of OP